# Declare template function to accept any container but only one contained type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to declare a function that accepts different STL containers, but they must contain objects of a specific class (e.g. it should accept `std::vector<double>` and `std::deque<double>` but no `std::vector<std::string>`).

I have found answers for templating both the container and the contained types, but my attempts to adapt them so that the contained type is fixed have been unsuccessful.

Comment: What *have* you tried? What problems have your attempts given you?

Comment: ^That. Hint: `value_type`

Comment: @PasserBy Are you talking about Henri Menke's second method? I had thought of static asserts, but thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it with template template arguments (no typo).  The first template argument of your template function is another template with a variadic number of template arguments.  The second template argument are the variadic template arguments.  In the signature you then fix the first template argument to the type you want (e.g. `double`) and let the compiler deduce the rest.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template < template < class ... > class Container, class ... Args >
void any_container(Container<double, Args...>)
{
    // print what was deduced
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vd;
    any_container(vd);

    std::deque<double> dd;
    any_container(dd);

    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    any_container(vs); // BOOM!
}
```

@PasserBy already hinted a different solution [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485084/declare-template-function-to-accept-any-container-but-only-one-contained-type/46485265#comment79924733_46485084).  Instead of having a substitution failure you could also just take the container as a template argument and the query its `value_type` in a `static_assert`.  This has the advantage that you can put a custom error message.

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container> void any_container(Container)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, double>::value,
                  "BOOM!");
    // print what was deduced
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vd;
    any_container(vd);

    std::deque<double> dd;
    any_container(dd);

    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    any_container(vs); // BOOM!
}
```

Comment: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not standard.  It is available in GCC and Clang and is not part of the preprocessor (in contrast to e.g. `__LINE__`).

Comment: So if I understood this correctly this is a bit of hack, right? I state that I will use a variadic number of template arguments which then turns out to be 0 every time, but that allows me to fix the first parameter, which wouldn't be possible otherwise. Is that it?

Comment: @user2891462 See the alternative solution below.

Comment: @user2891462 Also the variadic number of arguments is never zero in the above example.  `std::vector` has a second template argument which is the allocator, which defaults to the standard allocator.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I prefer the first method, since the type is clearer in the declaration of the function :)

Comment: @HenriMenke sizeof...(Args) is zero for (non std) containers that only have a value_type template parameter. It will also accept types that are not Containers, like `std::less`

Comment: @HenriMenke Does this work for initializer lists?  any_container({1, 2});